# Joomla 2.5 upgrade to 3.7.2 and subdomains

Tags: joomla-2.5

To whom it may concern:
I have joomla 2.5 and I am going to upgrade to 3.7.2 with its proper upgrade package.
There are subdomains in the root of main website which I want to upgrade, I believe if upgrade fails, there will be no effect on subdomains and their folders in the root of main website. Am I right or wrong?
P.S Subdomains are upgraded and backed up already too.
Kian William

Answer (score 2):

Normally this should not be a problem. Usually subdomains are located in their own folder and updating the main domain's Joomla installation should not affect the subdomains.

Comment: Then I shall update it, I already created backup with akeeba for all subdomains, thanks.